# Bind to certain item in ObservableCollection by checking value of string property

Tags: wpf, binding

In my View Model (VM) I have an ObservableCollection of items. In my view I am binding to the collection. I have created a few user controls that have a dependency property that i am binding to called STCode. So for example a "Tag" object will have a "Name" property of type String and a "value" property of type integer.

## In my ViewModel

```
Constructor
Tags.Add(new Tag("Tag1",111));
Tags.Add(new Tag("Tag2",222));
Tags.Add(new Tag("Tag3",333));
Tags.Add(new Tag("Tag4",444));

public ObservableCollection<Tag> Tags
 {
     get
     {
         return _TagList;
     }
     set
     {
         if (value != _TagList)
         {
             _TagList = value;
         }
     }
 }
```

## In my View

```
<my:UserControl1 x:Name="control1" Margin="12,89,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="257" Height="249" VerticalAlignment="Top" STCode="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
```

This will bind to the First items value property in the ObservableCollection (Showing "Tag1" value). Is there anyway that I can get a specific "tag" object from the observableCollection by specifying  the string Name property? So basically if I had 3 instances of my usercontrol in the view, on each control I would like to specify the "Name" property of the Tag object as a string in XAML, and in return bind that specific control to that specific tags integer "Value" property?

I hope this makes sense

## Model

```
public class Tag : ModelBase
{
    private int _value;
    public string Tagname { get; set; }
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
           return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}
```

## ModelBase

```
public class ModelBase :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why not just make a property for each Tag and bind to that?

Comment: I cant do that as there could be hundreds of tags

Comment: How about using an IValueConverter for your Binding and adjusting its Paramater according to your needs. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Comment: I dont think that is what I need. In the XAML I kind of need something like this :
    <my:UserControl1 x:Name="control1" STCode="{Binding TagName="Tag1" Path=Value}"/>

Comment: Then that's exactly what you need :) See my answer below, might need some fine tuning for your special need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your UserControls are bound to the Collection itself and not the Item on the collection (the converter does this job internally) you must call PropertyChanged on the whole Collection when you want to refresh the bindings on your usercontrols.

Edit: Full solution

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Tag> Tags { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Tags = new ObservableCollection<Tag>();
        Tags.Add(new Tag("Tag1", 111));
        Tags.Add(new Tag("Tag2", 222));
        Tags.Add(new Tag("Tag3", 333));
        Tags.Add(new Tag("Tag4", 444));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void ChangeRandomTag()
    {
        var rand = new Random();

        var tag = Tags[rand.Next(0, Tags.Count - 1)];

        tag.Value = rand.Next(0, 1000);

        OnPropertyChanged("Tags");
    }
}
```

View XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">

<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication1:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="1"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="2">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button x:Name="buttonChangeRandomTag"
                Click="ButtonChangeRandomTag_OnClick"
                Content="Change Random Tag Value" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tags, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=Tag1}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tags, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=Tag2}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tags, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=Tag3}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tags, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter=Tag4}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

View Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonChangeRandomTag_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (DataContext as MainWindowViewModel).ChangeRandomTag();
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ObservableCollection<Tag>), typeof(int))]
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = value as ObservableCollection<Tag>;
        var key = parameter as string;

        if (collection == null || parameter == null)
            return 0;

        var result = collection.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name.Equals(key));
        if (result == null)
            return 0;

        return result.Value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Tag Class:

```
public class Tag : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private int value;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == name) return;
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            if (value == this.value) return;
            this.value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public Tag(string name, int value)
    {
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined IObservableCollection localy in your application?

Comment: No thats a Typo. I will fix it in my answer

Comment: Perfect thank you for the reply. One last thing that is not working. If I use this XAML: <my:UserControl1 x:Name="control1"
STCode="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}" ConverterParameter="Tag1"/> The value propery is always Zero. However if I use this : <my:UserControl1 x:Name="control1"
STCode="{Binding Path=[0].Value, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}" ConverterParameter="Tag1"/> I get the actual value that is changing of that specific tag object. Any Ideas?

Comment: How does your DataContext look like? Have you tried debugging the Converters Convert Method?

Comment: The DataContext looks as follows in the constructor : 
TagViewModel tvm = new TagViewModel(); 
this.DataContext = tvm;

I have added a button in the view that executes this line of code:
tvm.Tags[0].Value = 111;

The strange thing is I also have a listView control on the page and i have bound the tagname and value to it. When I click the button to change the value to 111 the listviews value updates but the Binding to the UserControl does not update. If I put a break point in the Converter, the code is not being executed? Any Ideas?

Comment: Please provide your whole Tag class source code. My best guess is that you need to call RaisePropertyChanged("Tags");

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `ValueConverter` to do that for you:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(string))]
public class StringToTagPropertyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value != typeof(ObservableCollection<Tag>)) return 
DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        if (parameter as string == null) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        ObservableCollection<Tag> tagObject = (ObservableCollection<Tag>)value;
        string returnValue = tagObject.Where(t => t.Name.ToLower() == 
parameter.ToString().ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
        return returnValue ?? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; 
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
<my:UserControl1 x:Name="control1" Margin="12,89,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Width="257" Height="249" VerticalAlignment="Top" STCode="{Binding Tags, 
Converter={StaticResource StringToTagPropertyConverter}, 
ConverterParameter="Name"}" />
```

By changing the value of the `ConverterParameter`, you can get the `ValueConverter` to return different properties of your 'tag object'. I am assuming that you know how to add a value converter in XAML.

Comment: Passing the Tagname in as a Parameter is one step closer to the solution. What i need to do now is get the item in the Observable collection with that parameter as the "Name" property and return the value of that individual item in the collection

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. Please note that you will need to add `using System.Linq;` to use Linq in the `Converter` class.